# Can't get my Arduino code to read and send byte array (Arduino Mega 2560)

Tags: arduino

It is a communication between my computer and my Arduino. The computer sends commands through a GUI to the Arduino Mega 2560. The GUI code is written in C#.

Hope someone can figure out. What I am doing wrong? Thanks.

Besides: the start byte is 0x80, the command byte is 0x81, the unit byte is 0x01, the reserve byte is 0x0 and the stop byte is 0x3F. The bytes must come in this order. When an array of 5 has been read then it must perform it and send it back to the GUI.

```cpp
void handleDoorOpen(char one);
void handleDoorClose(char one);

void setup() {
  pinMode(13, OUTPUT);// define buttonPin. E.g. 13.
  Serial.begin(9600); // define your self
}

#define MAX_LENGTH 16
char data[MAX_LENGTH]; // Data array

void loop() {
  int count = 0;
  while (Serial.available() > 0) {
    // read the incoming byte:
    char incomingByte = (char)Serial.read();
    data[count] = incomingByte;
    count++;
    delay(25);
  }
  if (count >= 5 && data[0] == 0x80) {
    switch (data[1]) {
      case 0x81:
        handleDoorOpen(data[2]); // data[2] is unit
        Serial.write(data, count); // Send response back to C# wpf
        break;
      case 0x82:
        handleDoorClose(data[2]); // data[2] is unit
        Serial.write(data, count); // Send response back to C# wpf
        break;
      default:
        break;
        count = 0;
    }
  }
}

void handleDoorOpen(char one) {
  Serial.write(one);
}

void handleDoorClose(char one) {
  Serial.write(one);
}
```

This is the error/warning text I get from the compiler:

```
C:\Users\Rasef\OneDrive\Dokumenter\Arduino\gui_v_2\gui_v_2.ino: In function     'void loop()':

C:\Users\Rasef\OneDrive\Dokumenter\Arduino\gui_v_2\gui_v_2.ino:38:8:  warning: case label value exceeds maximum value for type

case 0x81:

    ^

C:\Users\Rasef\OneDrive\Dokumenter\Arduino\gui_v_2\gui_v_2.ino:44:8: warning: case label value exceeds maximum value for type

case 0x82:

    ^
```

Comment: This is the output. I don't get any errors, but nothing happens when I open my GUI.
And it is af if when I access my COM3 on my GUI my COM3 connection on my arduino stops working...

C:\Users\Rasef\OneDrive\Dokumenter\Arduino\gui_v_2\gui_v_2.ino: In function 'void loop()':

C:\Users\Rasef\OneDrive\Dokumenter\Arduino\gui_v_2\gui_v_2.ino:38:8: warning: case label value exceeds maximum value for type

   case 0x81:

        ^

C:\Users\Rasef\OneDrive\Dokumenter\Arduino\gui_v_2\gui_v_2.ino:44:8: warning: case label value exceeds maximum value for type

   case 0x82:

        ^

Comment: ahh sorry, my question is now updated.